# How do I get this Nginx server block working properly for front controller pattern?

Tags: php, nginx

I almost have it working, but even then not sure if it's properly implemented. (I'm new to Nginx!)

My test has this directory structure:

```
/index.php (root directory front controller)
/test/index.php (sub directory front controller)
/include/include.php (some PHP include)
```

Files named index.php are the front controllers.

The Nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    root /var/www/mysite.com/http;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }
}
```

These cases currently work and need to work like this:

```
1. http://mysite.com/ => /index.php (exists)
2. http://mysite.com/test => /test/index.php (exists)
3. http://mysite.com/test/index.php => /test/index.php (exists)
4. http://mysite.com/test/foobar => /index.php (/test/foobar didn't exist)
5. http://mysite.com/asdf => /index.php (/asdf didn't exist)
6. http://mysite.com/asdf.php => /index.php (/asdf.php didn't exist)
7. http://mysite.com/asdf/index.php => /index.php (didn't exist; the try_files @rewrite fixes this, otherwise I get "No input file specified.")
```

The case I don't have yet is:

```
8. http://mysite.com/include/include.php => /index.php
```

Currently accessing a PHP file that exists that isn't a front controller is processing that script. I can understand why it's doing it, it's `try(ing)_files $uri @rewrite` and finding include.php. I've been trying to fix it with rewrites, but no dice. Or is there a better way, with location blocks/`try_files`?

In general am I going about this server block correctly for my intentions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    root /var/www/mysite.com/http;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        location ~ /index\.php$ {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^ /index.php break;
            }
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }
}
```

This will serve ...

```
yoursite/any_path/ => yoursite/any_path/index.php
yoursite/any_path/index_file.php => yoursite/any_path/index.php
yoursite/any_path/any_non_index_file.php => yoursite/index.php
```

... which is what your question suggests you want (last one seems strange to me)

Comment: That fixed #8, but I had to rewrite it as the following to also fix #7: http://pastebin.com/RmFaeTHF

It may seem strange, but the idea is index.php is the only page users should ever access, and through includes and parsing the REQUEST_URI other stuff happens behind the scenes. Thanks!

Comment: I lied, the `try_files $uri @rewrite` prevents #7 but processing still happens after the try_files. Seems like using `if` is the fix..? http://paste.ubuntu.com/885844/

Comment: Correct. Your edit addresses #7 => Where there is no index.php file in the subject subdirectory. I'll update the answer for the benefit of future searchers.